# Reading string from file

Tags: c++, string, file

I've been stuck on this for a while. I'm trying to read a string from a file.
The string contains notes (A, G, C, B, etc.) which may be followed by certain values. For example, when a note is followed by '~', the note has added 20 to its duration (A~~ adds 40 to the preset duration). Other possible inputs:
A(4) should change the frequency by +4. 
B# should change the frequency by +20.

The input would look something like this: B(4)~F#(5)~~~Aa

I started by doing the following but I can't seem to figure out how to increment frequency with each additional '~' after a note.

```
string a;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); a++)
{
    if(a.at(i) == 'C')
    {
        frequency = 440;
        duration = 10;

        if(a.at(i++) == '~')
        {
            frequency += 20;
        }
    }
Values(frequency, duration)

}
```

Comment: Please mention your requirement clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The point in your loop that checks for a '~' is only reached when    a.at(i) == C, and only tests i++. add within the conditional for == '~' a loop:

```
if(a.at(i++) == '~'){
    while(a.at(i) == '~'){
        frequency += 20;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. My only other question is how to continually run the different values (~, #, (4), etc.) until another note is reached. Once the next note is reached how should the function return?

Comment: If you can safely assume that all "notes" are alphabetic, and only "notes" are alphabetic, you can use the built in function isalpha() to do this. isalpha(a.at(i)) will return true iff the parameter is an alphabetic character. To make that more clear: add the condition && !isalpha(a.at(i)) where needed so that you can exit your inner loops when you reach a "note"